# The Divisors of $s(2s+1)$ and Primes $2n+1$ and $3n+1$ part 1

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I want to check my math (and proof) on the following claim. The claim is by way of a computer search and a "hunch".

> ***claim:*** If $s$ is a prime number I write $\varphi_{s} =s(2s+1)$. Let  $\tau$ be the divisor function. If $\tau(\varphi_{s})=8$ and 
>   $3|\varphi_{s}$ then the following are true ;
>
> - if $q ={2s+1 \above 1.5pt 3}$ then $q$ divides $\varphi_{s}$
> - $q$ is prime or $q=3^{2}$
> - $q+\Bigl\lfloor {q \above 1.5pt 2} \Bigr\rfloor=s$
> - if $n = s-q$ then $2n+1 = q$ and $3n+1=s$

Let's work with an example real quick: If $s=439$ then $\varphi_{439} = 385881$. Observe that $\tau(385881) =8$. Now ${2(439)+1 \above 1.5pt 3} =293$ which is prime. Surely $293 + \lfloor {293 \above 1.5pt 2}\rfloor = 293+146=439$. Finally if $n = 439-293 = 146$ then $2*146+1 = 293$ and $3*146+1=439$.

***"proof:"*** I can quickly show that the divisors of $\varphi_{s}$ are: $$1,3,q,s,3q,3s,sq,\varphi_{s}$$
 Certainly $q$ is odd. Also note that $3<q<s$ and in particular $q \neq 3$ or $q \neq 7$. Now $3q=2s+1$ and $s3q = \varphi_{s}$. Certainly $(s,q)=1$ and $(s,3)=1$ so that $(s,3q)=1$. We can calculate $\tau(3sq)= \tau(s)\tau(3q) =8$ which shows that $\tau(3q)=4$. If $(3,q)=1$ then $\tau(3q)=\tau(3)\tau(q)=4$ and $\tau(q)=2$ in which case $q$ is prime.  Consider the cases $q=5$ or $q=9$:

If $q=5$ then $15=2s+1$. $14=2s$ and $s=7$. We can check that $\tau(\varphi_{7}) =8$. Also we can show that $5+\Bigl \lfloor {5 \above 1.5pt 2} \Bigr \rfloor=7$. Finally if $n=7-5$ then $2n+1=5$ and $3n+1=7$.

If $q=9$ then $27=2s+1$. $16=2s$ and $s=13$. We can check that $\tau(\varphi_{13}) =8$. Also we can show that $9+\Bigl \lfloor {9 \above 1.5pt 2} \Bigr \rfloor=13$. Finally if $n=13-9$ then $2n+1=9$ and $3n+1=13$.

Now Suppose that $(3,q)\neq 1$ and that $q>9$ is not prime. Then $q$ is divisible by $3,5$ or $7$ in which case we can write $q$ as $3k$, $5k$ or $7k$ for some odd positive number $k$. Consider $3k$. The case $k=1$ gives $q=9$ a case we already covered. If $k>1$ then $3q =3(3k)=9k$ which has as divisors: $1,3,9,k,3k,9k$. If $k>1$ then $\tau(3q)>4$ a contradiction.  A similar argument holds for $5k$ and $7k$.

The remaining assertions are technical calculations. Observe that

\begin{align*} 
q+ \Bigl\lfloor {q \above 1.5pt 2} \Bigr\rfloor &= \Bigl\lfloor q + {q \above 1.5pt 2} \Bigr\rfloor = \Bigl\lfloor {3q \above 1.5pt 2} \Bigr\rfloor = \bigl \lfloor {2s+1 \above 1.5pt 2} \Bigr\rfloor = \Bigl\lfloor {2s \above 1.5pt 2} \Bigr\rfloor + \Bigl\lfloor {1 \above 1.5pt 2} \Bigr\rfloor = s 
\end{align*}
Now the fourth assertion is simple we can show that $s-q = {s-1 \above 1.5pt 3}$ then 
\begin{align*}
 2\Bigg({s-1\above 1.5pt 3}\Bigg)+1 &= {2s-2+3 \above 1.5pt 3} = {2s+1 \above 1.5pt 3}= q
\end{align*}
Finally 
\begin{align*}
3\Bigg({s-1 \above 1.5pt 3}\Bigg)+1 &= s-1+1 = s 
\end{align*}

Compare $q$ to the sequence [A158708](https://oeis.org/A158708/) from the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. The table below lists small values for $s$, $\varphi_{s}$, the divisors of $\varphi_{s}$, $q$ and $k$. You can verify that $4k+1=q$ and $6k+1 =s$.

\begin{array}{| l | l | l | l |l|}
\hline
s & \varphi_{s} & divisors \; of\; \varphi_{s}\;\tau(\varphi_{s})=8 & q & k\\ \hline
7 & 105 & 1, 3, 5 ,7, 15, 21, 35, 105 & 5 & 1\\ 
13 & 351 & 1, 3 ,9 ,13 ,27, 39, 117, 351 & {\color{red} 9=3^{2}} & 2 \\ 
19 & 741 & 1, 3, 13 ,19, 39, 57, 247, 741 & 13 & 3 \\ 
43 & 3741 & 1 ,3 ,29, 43 ,87 ,129 ,1247 ,3741 & 29 & 7 \\ 
61 & 7503 & 1 ,3 ,41 ,61 ,123 ,183 ,2501 ,7503 & 41 & 10 \\ 
79 & 12561 & 1 ,3 ,53 ,79 ,159 ,237 ,4187 ,12561 & 53 & 13 \\ 
109 & 23871 & 1 ,3 ,73 ,109 ,219 ,327 ,7957 ,23871 & 73 & 18 \\ 
151 & 47573 & 1 ,3 ,101 ,151 ,303 ,453 ,15251 ,45753 & 101 & 25 \\ 
163 & 53301 & 1 ,3 ,109 ,163 ,327 ,489 ,17767 ,53301 & 109 & 27 \\ 
223 & 99681 & 1 ,3 ,149 ,223 ,447 ,669 ,33227 ,99681 & 149 & 37  \\ 
271 & 147153 & 1 ,3 ,181 ,271 ,543 ,813 ,49051 ,147153 & 181  & 45 \\ 
349 & 243951 & 1 ,3 ,233 ,349 ,699 ,1047 ,81317 ,243951 & 233 & 58 \\ 
421 & 354903 & 1 ,3 ,281 ,421 ,843 ,1263 ,118301 ,354903 & 281 & 70 \\ 
439 & 385881 & 1 ,3 ,293 ,439 ,879 ,1317 ,128627 ,385881 & 293 & 73 \\ 
    \hline
    \end{array}

***Update***: We can write $k= {s-q \above 1.5pt 2}$ so that $2k =s-q$.

Comment: Is there a typo? On the first line you have "If $\sigma(\varphi_s)=8$." There are not many $k$ such that $\sigma(k)=8$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas nope you read that correctly. $\sigma(\varphi_{s}) = 8$. And what do you mean by there are "not many"?

Comment: The only integer $k$ such that $\sigma(k)=8$ is $k=7$, which is not $s(2s+1)$ for any prime $s$. So the "general" computations afterwards seem unnecessary.

Comment: Hmm? If $s=13$ the $13(2*13+1) = 351$. And the divisors of $351$ are $1,3,9,13,27,39,117$ and $351$. I count $8$ of them. Remember $\sigma$ counts composite divisors also?

Comment: I guess you are using your own notation. The standard meaning of $\sigma(k)$ is the **sum** of the divisors of $k$. The usual notation for the **number** of divisors is $d(k)$, though sometimes $\sigma_0(k)$ is used.

Comment: I will edit and use $d(k)$ to be more consistent with established notation.

Comment: Another classical name is $\tau(n)$, particularly in the German literature.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, the tau function $\tau(n)$ actually defines the number of divisors of $n$, so the OP is using the correct notation. Yes, $\sigma_0(n)$ will also work.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez, doesn't $\phi_s$ or $\phi(s)$ equal $s - 1$ for any prime number $s$?

Comment: @obinna No it does not. I believe some of you might be "Lost In Notation". I am going by the notational suggestion of Andre Nicolas and using $\tau$ to count the number of divisors.

Comment: @obinna I am defining or "writing" $\varphi_{s}$ to be $s(2s+1)$ it is a function in $s$. Perhaps you are confusing this with Euler's phi function $\phi(s)$.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now.